# Filling CSS grid with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a personal project with a `canvas` that is a CSS grid. It is 17 rows and columns and instead of adding 289 `div`s manually, that I would create a for loop to do it for me when the page loads.

JavaScript:

```
var row = 1;
var column = 1;

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 289; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.color = "gray";
    div.style.gridRow = row;
    div.style.gridColumn = column;
    column += 1;
    if (column == 17) {
      row += 1;
      column = 0;
    }
    console.log("test");
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="init();">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

This is the only 'version' that I've tried that doesn't spit an error at me, but still nothing shows up. It runs though, because the console displays `"test"`.

I've tried replacing:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
```

with

```
var div = document.canvas.createElement("div");`,  
var div = document.myCanvas.createElement("div");
```

...etc. (which probably aren't the right syntax but I tried them anyway) and it gives me this error when evaluating  `document.myCanvas.createElement`:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object
```

Basically I just want each grid box in the `canvas` to be filled using JS when the page loads. Also, I'm very new to programming so simple terms are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't worked too much with `canvas` but I'm pretty sure you should be drawing to the `canvas` rather than trying to `create` a new element which doesn't seem to have `append`.

Comment: `column = 0` in `if (column == 17) {
      row += 1;
      column = 0;
    }` should probably be `column = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a `div` that had the `canvas` inside it and replacing:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
```

with:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
document.getElementById("background").appendChild(newDiv);
```

and it worked great.